# spinner item selection inside button onclick not working

Tags: android, spinner

Below inside my adapter class as i will get data inside button click i want to populate spinner inside button click and set item selected listener in it.

```
tvMediaCategory.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    for(int i=0; i<mediaList.get(position).getMediaCatList().size(); i++)
                    {
                        catArr[i] = mediaList.get(position).getMediaCatList().get(i).getCategoryName();
                    }
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                for(int i=0; i<catArr.length; i++)
                {adapter.add(catArr[i]);}
                adapter.add("HINT_TEXT_HERE"); //This is the text that will be displayed as hint.

                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount()); //set the hint the default selection so it appears on launch.
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                               int position, long id) {
                        Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        Toast.makeText(context, "position clicked "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
                tvMediaCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner.performClick();

                //showCategoryDlg(catArr, position, selectedPos, tvMediaCategory);

            }               
        }
    });
```

here my spineer not getting open but selecting default item. how to make it work. this my code is inside a adapter. how can i show my spinner items on click of button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example... i am sure you will be able to get what u r looking for....
you need to implement the onItemSelectedListener

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example